# Two Different Crystal Resonator on Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino, crystal

I'm looking to building my own circuit board based on the Arduino Mega 2560 and looked into their schematic. There are two micro-controllers on there; the ATMega2560 and the ATMega16U2. Both of them have their own 16MHz crystal. But their crystal is slightly different from each other.

The ATMega2560 is connected to this [crystal with its built in capacitors](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Ceramic-Resonators_MuRata_CSTCE16M0V53-R0_16M-0-5-15pF_C32180.html)  with a load capacitance of 15pF. However, the ATMega16U2 is connected to a [different crystal](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/SMD-Crystal-Resonators_Seiko-Epson_Q24FA20H00247_Seiko-Epson-Q24FA20H00247_C255949.html) (load capacitance of 16pF) and requires external capacitors. The specs of the two are pretty much the same as far as I can see.

Would it not make sense to just use make both crystals the same model? Is there a reason as to why they are different? I looked at the price of both and they're about the same. Would my design still work if I just replaced the crystal on the 16U2 with the one on the 2560?

[image]

**Crystal Schematic on the 2560**

[image]

**Crystal Schematic on the 16U2**

Comment: That's not a crystal on the 2560, it's a ceramic resonator.

Comment: I didn't know that until now. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

The ATmega16U2 uses a quartz crystal because it needs a very accurate and stable frequency for USB. The ATmega2560 uses a ceramic resonator which is less accurate, but cheaper (lower unit cost, fewer parts, smaller board area).

If saving a few cents isn't important then you could use a quartz crystal for both MCUs. This would make your board more suitable for applications requiring high accuracy, eg. a real-time clock or frequency counter.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the info/answer!